# How do I check if a variable is an imaginary number inside JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, numbers

I am making a calculator, and I don't want NaN to show up for results of imaginary/complex numbers, and instead just an error message. How would I check this inside of JavaScript?

I looked around on the web but couldn't find a definitive answer.

Comment: try searching for "complex numbers"

Comment: You can use `isNaN(number)` to check for this, and display the error.

Comment: JavaScript doesn’t have complex math built in

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks, since 'isNan' is only checked when I'm using exponents, it works great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `isNaN()`.

```js
let x;

const rand = Math.round(Math.random());

if (rand) x = 5 + 1;
else x = 5 + "a";

if (isNaN(x)) console.log("error");
else console.log(x);
```

Comment: `NaN` can happen for reasons that aren't imaginary/complex numbers. Potential for bugs